# Return to Previous Activity without Calling

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everything is working good but the thing is after executing the called activity it automatically redirected back to the calling activity. Is any way to avoid this. I want to stay the same activity until the user click back button.

Here is my calling dashboard Activity--(Calling Activity)

```
private CardView additem,edititem,pendingorder,history;
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_admin, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    logout_process();
    return true;

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_dashboard);

    additem=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.additem);
    edititem=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.edititem);
    pendingorder=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.pendingorder);
    history=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.history);
    floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.scanner);


    additem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        startActivity(new Intent(shop_dashboard.this,additem.class));
    });
    edititem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        startActivity(new Intent(shop_dashboard.this,additem.class));
    });
    pendingorder.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        startActivity(new Intent(shop_dashboard.this,additem.class));
    });
    history.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        startActivity(new Intent(shop_dashboard.this,additem.class));
    });
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Scanner",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

}
private void logout_process() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Logout",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    Intent intent=new Intent(shop_dashboard.this, Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

}

Called Activity --(Called Activity)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_additem);

    itemnameEt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    priceEt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
    quantityEt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.categorygroup);
    circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.item_image);
    additem=(Button)findViewById(R.id.itemadd);
    progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressadditem);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    type="Drinks";
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Items");
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    circleImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    });

    additem.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        itemName=itemnameEt.getText().toString();
        price=priceEt.getText().toString();
        quantity=quantityEt.getText().toString();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(itemName))
        {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(price))
            {
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(quantity))
                {
                    addingitem();
                }
                else
                {
                    quantityEt.setError("Please Enter Quantity");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                priceEt.setError("Please Enter Price");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            itemnameEt.setError("Please Enter Item Name");
        }
    });

}

private void addingitem()
{
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(FilePathUri != null)
    {
        storageReference2=storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));
        storageReference2.putFile(FilePathUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    storageReference2.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {

                        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Items");
                        helperclass_additem helpers = new helperclass_additem(itemName,price,quantity,type,uri.toString());
                        String user = Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();
                        databaseReference.child(user).child(type).child(itemName).setValue(helpers).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(additem.this, "Item Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(additem.this, "Failed To Add", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        });

                    });

                });


    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(additem.this, "Please Select Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        FilePathUri =data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),FilePathUri);
            circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    switch (checkedId)
    {
        case R.id.breakfast:
            type="Breakfast";
            break;
        case R.id.lunch:
            type="Lunch";
            break;
        case R.id.snacks:
            type="Snacks";
            break;
        case R.id.drinks:
            type="Drinks";
            break;
        case R.id.others:
            type="Others";
            break;
    }
}
public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri)) ;

}
```

helperclass_additem

```
public helperclass_additem() {
}

public helperclass_additem(String itemName, String price, String quantity, String category, String imageUrl) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.category = category;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getVisibility() {
    return visibility;
}

public void setVisibility(String visibility) {
    this.visibility = visibility;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps your "onOptionItemSelected" function is called? Which then calls logout? Did you try debugging and see where in the code you are reaching the logout from?

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 300 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.